# Unplug a new hard drive without umount?

Tags: hard-disk

Before I unplug a external hard drive with file systems, I use `umount`. But my new hard drive doesn't have anything on it yet. (no file systems). 
I connect it to my laptop using a sata-usb adapter.
Is it safe to unplug the hard drive directly?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be safe.

The normal reason for unmounting is because the OS doesn't always write everything to the drive immediately when software makes changes. It holds some data in memory, and writes it to the disk at the most opportune time. If you unplug a disk before everything has been written, you'll lose those changes. Part of the process of unmounting a disk is to make sure that everything has been written.

If you haven't yet used the drive for anything, there's nothing that needs to be written. Unplugging the drive can't lose anything.